# node.js in production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to set-up node environment in my production system. I installed node in my local system its fine, after that i checked for version `node -v`.

Now i installed node in my production system using `sudo apt get install nodejs` and now i checked the version `node -v` nothing happened but i used `nodejs -v`, its working.

Also in my local system i used `node filename.js` to run my node app. But in my production system i have to use `nodejs filename.js`. I dont know why this happening? Also whether it will create problem in my production. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more linux specific question. You can create a symlink to use `node` instead of `nodejs`. Command example here:

```
sudo ln -sT $(which nodejs) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: This only works if `/usr/local/bin` is checked before the directory of the pre-installed node. Off the top of my head, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: All packages binary put in `/usr/bin` so it's very little chance of collision.

Comment: @vanadium23 thanks    
 
thanks. Then it wont create problem right? Also my node API is running in port 2500, when i use curl command curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET localhost:2500/xx/yy/zzz i am receiving empty reply from server. Could you please hare your ideas why its happening?

Comment: @Subburaj too broad question to answer, without example of code it will be a wild guess

Answer (score 1):

This is because your particular distribution of linux already has a `node` binary.

You're more than likely not using it for anything. You have two options.

1. rename the pre-installed `node` to something else, and rename `nodejs` to `node`
2. rename `nodejs` to `node` but make sure to adjust your `$PATH` so that node.js's directory is loading before the pre-installed `node`

Comment: thanks. Then it wont create problem right? Also my node API is running in port 2500, when i use curl command curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:2500/xx/yy/zzz i am receiving empty reply from server. Could you please hare your ideas why its happening?